# Hadoop can't find joda dependency

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, jodatime

I've tried to write a mapreduce app that takes input from a CSV file and aggregates rollover interest per account. I've passed my MRunit tests and everything seems to check out. When I try to run the jar file on my machine (I'm running Hadoop locally), the following error comes up

```
..........>>
14/07/16 09:09:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/07/16 09:09:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
14/07/16 09:09:05 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1566570594_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
    at org.mrIntCalc.CalcInterestMapper.map(CalcInterestMapper.java:38)
    at org.mrIntCalc.CalcInterestMapper.map(CalcInterestMapper.java:12)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 11 more
14/07/16 09:09:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1566570594_0001 running in uber mode : false
14/07/16 09:09:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/07/16 09:09:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1566570594_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
14/07/16 09:09:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

I built the app using maven, so joda(v2.3) is listed as a dependency in the pom.xml. Like I said, my unit tests came out all clear. Looking up this issue, I see that some people mention there's a classpath issue at the root of this, although I don't think that's quite it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied the joda-time.jar to a hadoop common library. Probably not the best solution, but at least it works.

Comment: You ever find a better solution for this?

Comment: @DJElbow this is the solution I stuck with. I did this in Eclipse so you can either manually download and add the dependent jar file to the classpath or that.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether  joda-time*.jar exists in your classpath/buildpath
If it is not mentioned, add it.
Else, copy that jar into your lib directory and add it into your classpath.

Comment: This type of answer should be in a comment.