# Facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant error even after adding the joda-time libarary in class path

Tags: hive, jodatime

I have a java class that uses joda-time library classes. I am able to import the joda time classes and run my class in eclipse.

When I am trying to add my class in hive environment then I am facing error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant). Even this class is present in class path, and have also added the joda-time jar explicitly. Inside joda-time jar, org/joda/time/ReadableInstant is already present.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.getUdfClass(FunctionTask.java:313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.createTemporaryFunction(FunctionTask.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.execute(FunctionTask.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop can't find joda dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781932/hadoop-cant-find-joda-dependency)

Comment: In my case also, I copied the joda-time.jar to a Hive common library, But that's not the best solution. Looking for some other solution.